# Default values in kwargs with class inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have two classes `A` and `B(A)`.  Their constructor accept the `style` dictionary as a keyword argument.

For `A` objects I want, by default, the string `green` to be associated to `style['color']`.

For `B` objects `color` defaults to `red`.

I came up with this solution but find it rather clumsy.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        style = kwargs.pop('style', {})
        if 'color' not in style:
            style['color'] = 'green'
        print(style)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        style = kwargs.pop('style', {})
        if 'color' not in style:
            style['color'] = 'red'
        super().__init__(style=style, **kwargs)

A()  #  {'color': 'green'}
B()  #  {'color': 'red'}
B(style={'color': 'blue'})  #  {'color': 'blue'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead.

It introduces a helper method to the base class called `default_kwarg`.

This can be called in both cases (superclass and subclass) to set the default value of the `color` key.

This approach also enables the `style` dict to contain other key/value pairs. I've added an extra example at the end that demonstrates this.

```
class A:
    def default_kwarg(self, arg, default):
        arg = arg.pop('style', {})
        if 'color' not in arg:
          arg['color'] = default
        return arg

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        style = self.default_kwarg(kwargs, 'green')
        print(style)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['style'] = self.default_kwarg(kwargs, 'red')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

A()  #  {'color': 'green'}
B()  #  {'color': 'red'}
B(style={'color': 'blue'})  #  {'color': 'blue'}
B(style={'something': 'else'})  #  {'something': 'else', 'color': 'red'}
```

You could also generalize this helper method quite easily to apply defaults to other keys in the dict.

Comment: OK, sounds like a cleaner solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks slightly cleaner but it still feels a bit hacky:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.style = kwargs.get('style', {'color': 'green'})
        print(self.style)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['style'] = kwargs.get('style', {'color': 'red'})
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

A()  #  {'color': 'green'}
B()  #  {'color': 'red'}
B(style={'color': 'blue'})
```

If `style` is actually `self.style` which I'm assuming it is, you can relegate the assignment to the parent class since it will always get there with `super()` anyway.

This assumes that  aren't attempting to pull `'style'` from `kwargs` afterwards. You shouldn't need to since it's already assigned to `self.style`.

You probably noticed that it would also fail if you would pass in `style` but not assign a `'color'` to it. If you're planning on doing this, you would probably be better off just setting `color` as a default keyword argument.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, color='green', **kwargs):
        self.style = kwargs.get('style', {'color': color})
        self.style['color'] = self.style.get('color', color)
        print(self.style)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, color='red', **kwargs):
        kwargs['style'] = kwargs.get('style', {'color': color})
        super().__init__(color=color, **kwargs)

A()  #  {'color': 'green'}
B()  #  {'color': 'red'}
B(style={'font': 'Times New Roman'})  #  {'color': 'red'}
B(style={'color': 'blue'})
```